# Laravel Sanctum, VUE 3 Auth 401 unauthorized error

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, authentication, laravel-sanctum

I'm struggling with unauthorized 401 error Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/user Request Method: GET Status Code: 401 Unauthorized Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin while I' am after login trying acces to user. After login is token always stored in personal acces tokens inside database. When i am trying this through postman manually, i login take token from login and put it to /api/user it work and show it details about current logged user. Please I am lost, can anyone try to give me any advice?

This is my routes in Laravel

```
<?php


Route::prefix('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/login', LoginController::class);
    Route::post('/logout', LogoutController::class)->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    Route::post('/register', RegisterController::class);
});

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

This is login controller.

```
<?php

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(LoginRequest $request){
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if(!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => ['The credentials you entered are incorrect.']
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $user->createToken('laravel_api_token')->plainTextToken
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is my cors config.

```
<?php

return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'auth/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

This is sanctum config

```
return [



    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:5173,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),
```

Stateful domains in env

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost,localhost:8000,localhost:3000,localhost:5173,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,127.0.0.1:5173,::1
```

API calls in VUE3

```
import api from "./api";
export const csrfCookie = () => api.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie");
export const login = (credentials) => api.post("/api/auth/login", credentials);
export const register = (user) => api.post("/api/auth/register", user);
export const logout = () => api.post("/api/auth/logout");
console.log(login);
export const getUser = () => api.get("/api/user");
```

Auth-store in vue 3

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { computed, ref } from "vue";
import { csrfCookie, login, register, logout, getUser } from "../http/auth-api";
export const useAuthStore = defineStore("authStore", () => {
  const user = ref(null);
  const isLoggedIn = computed(() => !!user.value);
  const fetchUser = async () => {
    const { data } = await getUser();
    user.value = data;
  };
  const handleLogin = async (credentials) => {
    await csrfCookie();
    await login(credentials);
    await fetchUser();
  };
  const handleRegister = async (newUser) => {
    await register(newUser);
    await handleLogin({
      email: newUser.email,
      password: newUser.password,
    });
  };
  const handleLogout = async () => {
    await logout();
    user.value = null;
  };
  return {
    user,
    isLoggedIn,
    fetchUser,
    handleLogin,
    handleRegister,
    handleLogout,
  };
});
```

Axios

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL,
})


export default api
```

I am trying to solve unathorized error. But everything seems to be fine..I dont know any more solutions.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have trimmed it.